# Attempted to read or write protected memory when converting to CSV

Tags: c#, oledb

I've read up on this error but do not know how to fix.  Short synopsis of the automation:

1. I am passed a file out of an application in a .txt format that contains html tags.
2. I must convert this file to csv and amend some headers before passing it on to it's final destination.
3. to facilitate this, I'm connecting to the text file via OleDB
4. I get this error on maybe 1% of the files that are processed with hundreds of files processed thus far.
5. I've segmented off the code to run only this to eliminate other potential errors within the code.
6. I've added the below to allow it to fall into the error handing process but the error remains when I attempt to move the file to the error log folder.

[System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute()]

Any help is much apperciated.

Here is a code snippet.

```
    public static void ConvertExcelToCsv(string excelFilePath, string csvOutputFile, string fileExtType, int worksheetNumber = 1,  bool SQLDataInsert = false)
    {

      switch (fileExtType)
        {
             case ".txt":
                    cnnStr = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"HTML Import;IMEX=1;HDR=NO\"", excelFilePath);
               break;
            default:
                cnnStr = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO\"", excelFilePath);
                break;
        }
       var cnn = new OleDbConnection(cnnStr);  
       var dt = new DataTable();
       try
        {
            cnn.Open();  // fails here
            string worksheet = schemaTable.Rows[worksheetNumber - 1]["table_name"].ToString().Replace("'", "");
            string sql = String.Format("select * from [{0}]", worksheet);
            var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
             cnn.Dispose();
             GeneralFunctions.DisplayTextConsole("Error received trying to process File: " + excelFilePath.ToString(), ConsoleColor.Red, ConsoleColor.White, false);
             File.Move(excelFilePath, Constant._ErrorFileDir + @"\" + Path.GetFileName(ErrFileName));
         }
      }
```

Comment: can you provide some sample files?

Comment: The `cnn.Dispose()` should be in the `finally` block rather than the `catch` block. Although I don't think that'll help with the problem in the question.

Comment: Check following folder for a file msadoXX.dll. Version should match your oledb version number in the connection string : C:\Program Files\Common Files\system\ado

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I can't provide file samples as they're internal documents. I suspect the file differs but I cannot distinguish the two upon manual review.  The dll file i have is msado15.dll in that folder.  This error physically crashes the application which cannot happen. I can deal with a 1% failure rate but I just need the coding to release the file so I can move it out of the way.

Comment: If you comment out the `cnn.Open()` and let the dataadapter take care of opening (and subsequently automatically closing) the connection, does the error happen on a different line?

Comment: Andrew - thanks again.  Yes, when I comment out the cnn.Open() the file is successfully moved to the error folder.

Comment: @user1628449 Well, that surprises me a bit, but if it works.... Oh, and the Dispose really does need to be in the finally block, otherwise it could build up undisposed cnns and fall over from resource exhaustion.

Comment: @AndrewMorton thanks - I put the dispose there in an attempt to free the file from whatever is stopping me from moving it.  The file moves file without attempting to connect  when comment out. However, when I uncomment the open command, it throws the protected memory error which I can suppress/ignore with  `[System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute()]` but I am still unable to move because it says the file is in use.